# My URL Hash value (http://example.com#test) replaced to (http://example.com#!#test)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, hash

I am trying to make my web page as single page with javascript/jQuery. I have to change the content on the basis of #value in the url. but the issue i am facing issue my hash sign (#) in url changed to #!#. it look very ugly. i want my url should be like. 
http://example.com/#demo
but actual result is like 
http://example.com/#!#demo

if i remove angular from my page then it work fine but with angular hash tag is change to #!#. I dont want to use angular routing because my view is same. I am using angular only one page of my website. won't load template via routers.

thanks in advance

Comment: no.. this is quietly different question. I am not using any kind of angular routing i am just want get ride #!#,  only #UrlTg

Comment: You may want to be using a different tag? From this tag's description: "[f]or questions about URLs and HTML anchors, use fragment-identifier."